# Leaflet is not showing Control.extend data in IE/Safari till a move or click on map

Tags: css, internet-explorer, safari, leaflet, innerhtml

Leaflet is not showing Control.extend data in IE and safari.
IE shows the counters box after a move on map. 
Safari shows the box after a click.

For my 2nd extention(popup) safari needs 2 clicks on the marker.
And IE only shows it while holding the mousebutton down.

Expected result:

[image: This is how it should look like]

Chrome, Edge and Firefox are working fine.

The reworked code:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Bee-Idees kaart</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup.js'></script>
</head>
<style>
.my-custom-counters {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background: #7ab51d;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 11px;
    width: 310px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #3A8D45;
    border-width: 1px;
    opacity: 0.85;
}
.my-custom-counters .ImpactHeader {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 14px;
   text-align: center;
   font-weight: 600;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.my-custom-counters .ImpactLead {
font-weight: 500;
}

.my-custom-counters .ImpactCount {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.my-custom-counters .ImpactEnd {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.my-custom-counters:empty {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="map" style="height: 580px; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>
</body>

<script>
markers = [
{
    "name": "Gouda 3",
    "lat": 52.021616,
    "lng": 4.687917, 
    "marker": "red"
}
];
</script>  

<script>
var iconBase = 'css\\icons\\';
// Standard fields
var groupLabel = [];
groupLabel[0] = "Red";

var map = L.map('map', {
center: [52.021616, 4.85],
zoom: 10
});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}).addTo(map);

var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup(),
group0 = L.featureGroup.subGroup(mcg),
control = L.control.layers(null, null, { collapsed: false }), i, a, title, m; 
mcg.addTo(map);

var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
var iconName = iconBase + markers[i].marker + ".png";
var myIcon = L.icon({ iconUrl: iconName, iconAnchor:   [20, 40] }) 
var popup = '<h2>' + markers[i].name + '</h2>';

var m = L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], {icon: myIcon, title: markers[i].name} )
              .bindPopup( popup );

if (markers[i].marker === "red") { m.addTo(group0);} 
}

control.addOverlay(group0, groupLabel[0]);
control.addTo(map);

group0.addTo(map); 

map.addLayer(mcg);
var MyCounters = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
        position: 'bottomright'
    },
    onAdd: function (map) {
        return L.DomUtil.create('div', 'my-custom-counters');
    },
    setContent: function (content) {
        this.getContainer().innerHTML = content;
    }
});
myCounters = new MyCounters().addTo(map);
showCounters();

function showCounters() {
impact = '<div class="ImpactHeader">TOTAAL GEMETEN IMPACT VAN ALLE PROJECTEN<br>ZICHTBAAR OP DE KAART<br> </div> <div class="undefined"> <table style="width:100%;"> <tr> <td> <div class="ImpactLead">Winst besteed aan kansarmen : </div> </td> <td> <div class="ImpactCount">275 </div> </td> <td> <div class="ImpactEnd">€ (Euro) </div> </td> </tr><tr> <td> <div class="ImpactLead">Toegang tot financiële diensten: </div> </td> <td> <div class="ImpactCount">176 </div> </td> <td> <div class="ImpactEnd">Personen </div> </td> </tr><tr> <td> <div class="ImpactLead">Veilig en gezond voedsel: </div> </td> <td> <div class="ImpactCount">250 </div> </td> <td> <div class="ImpactEnd">Personen </div> </td> </tr></table> </div>'
myCounters.setContent(impact);
}
</script>
</html>
```

It seems IE can't handle adding a bit more complex string to extend.

Answer (score 2):

Your custom Controls are originally empty.

If you want them filled from the start, you should at least call your `showCounters` function just after you add your Counters Control to the map. Same for your Popup Control.

For the latter, you use a `popup` option, `buildPopupinfo` function and several variables (`Maps`, `Markers` and `popup`) that you do not explain / show how you assign them. The issue looks to be very probably in those.

---

**After question edit with new code:**

Hum you seem to encounter an IE bug with `:empty` CSS pseudo-selector and dynamically filling the element with `innerHTML`.

It seems that simply wrapping your HTML content with a **single** outer element (like a `<div>`) avoids this bug:

```js
// The "one" Element is filled with a SINGLE child (but it can have many grand children)
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = '<div> <div>one</div> <div>one</div> </div>';

// The "two" Element is filled with 2 children nodes
// Try clicking somewhere else on the page to "reveal" it
document.getElementById('two').innerHTML = '<div>two</div><div>two</div>';
```

```css
.auto-hide {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}

.auto-hide:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="auto-hide"></div>
<div id="two" class="auto-hide"></div>
```

I guess you have a similar CSS rule for your popup, hence a similar behaviour.

I am totally unable to reproduce the issue on Safari (11.1) with the above code snippet or with the code provided in the question:

https://plnkr.co/edit/YDbSFQeaUYtVBadKnnbU?p=preview

Comment: showCounters is called after all JSON data has been collected to calculate all impact in scope. Plz keep in mind that Chrome, Edge and Firefox are handling it as expected.

Comment: At a marker click all the popup info is combined to one large html string in buildPopupinfo and passed to the setContent.
Again Chrome, Edge and firefox are working fine.
Only IE and Safari dont

Comment: That may be so, but you do not provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to let people properly investigate. You can easily understand that without it, and with missing pieces from your code, it is impossible to help you further, especially given the weird compatibility behaviour you describe. Keep in mind that while people help you on their free time, that is no reason to waste it. By providing enough data in your question, you will get more relevant help and make the best of everyone's time.

Comment: Sorry about not loading the full code.   The project can now be reached as:  https://markup-mvc-test.azurewebsites.net//leaflet/leaflet.html

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and include there the minimum code to reproduce your issue. While linking to your external server is a step forward, it will not help future readers who might no longer have access to it. Not even talking about the expectation that you strip down your project to the only part that creates the issue. Finally, editing your question will bump it up, so it will be more visible and hopefully more people could help you.

Comment: Sorry that it took me a while to rework the code to 1 smaller html file. I'm glad i could use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49149552/revisions as base

Answer (score 0):

Tnx for the solution. 
Wrapping my content for both (showCounters and buildPopupinfo) with a extra div did it for IE.

Safari is still not working. 
It still needs a click on the map for the showCounters and 2 clicks on the marker for the buildPopupinfo.

Comment: Use _comments_ instead of an _answer_ textarea if you do not provide a solution to your issue.

Comment: Sorry I could not reproduce your issue on Safari 11.1. See the Plunker link in my edited answer.

Comment: So i guess it's my safari for windows crapping up. I've seen a lot of remarks about safari needing 2 clicks on older versions. I'll let the one who tested it on his iphone test it again.   Consider  it as closed

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Please mark the answer that helped you solve your issue as _accepted_, so that people know your question is closed.